# How to append an element condition from css value

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

I need to add some css for element with less than 0 opacity, this value changing dynamically. How to set condition for this element if that situation is alive.

```
if ($('#rounded_items li').css("opacity" < "0")){
    $(this).css('display','none');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense, opacity can't be less than zero.

Comment: i know but i use roundabout.js script and it set this value less than 0 and i can only catch this  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var opacity = Number($('#rounded_items li').css("opacity"));

 something.css('display', opacity < 0 ? 'none' : 'block');
```

**Note**: Opacity is never `< 0`. Always between 0 an 1 :)

Comment: i use roundabout.js script at it set opactity for less than 0 ;) this is only valu that i can catch and set some condition ;)

Comment: what you mean improve? :) so, your solutions is warnking but it's set block value for every condition even if opacity is less than 0 :(

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski: In my code I've used `< 1`. Sorry about that. Will change back to `0` inline with your question.

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski: Then you should be doing this from a place where you are changing that attribute. Like a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution solution, not as nice as robin's:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Wr56/

```
<div class="zero">Zero Opacity</div>
<div class="full">Full Opacity</div>

.zero { opacity:0; }
.full{ opacity:1; }

$("div").each(function() {

    if( $(this).css("opacity") === '0' )
    {
        $(this).css('display','none');
    }    

});
```

Comment: i can't set two other calesses for this elements, it always have the same calss